# Typescript transpile only typescript but also typecheck javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on a node project which contains javascript code. In javascript I use jsdoc to denote types. I wanted to add a class using typescript. Now I want to typecheck both js and ts files in the project because it helps me to find errors but I don't want to emit transpiled js. I only need to transpile ts files.

I have checked the [compiler options of typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html). In order to get typechecking in javascript I have  to add `allowJS` and `checkJS`. But it also causes js files to transpile. I can disable transpiling by `noEmit` but then it also doesn't transpile ts files. So is there an option like 'emit only typescript'?

Comment: Are you sure that you can mix es6 modules (es6 not transpiled with import, exports and maybe included in the html as type="module") with transpiled typescript (that is es5)? I think that you will get an error from js!

Comment: Your only option is to transpile all the files or none of the files

Comment: @asdru It is possible to target es6 or other javascript versions(with `--target`). So I don't think that would cause a problem.